# Geometry library for Java

Tags: java, geometry

Is there any geometry library available for Java? I'm looking for solution to get an intersection point(s) between two geometry objects.

Comment: What are the dimensions of the space you are working in? 2D, 3D?

Comment: Off topic? You gonna be kidding me. Lets close all Java questions then.

Comment: You seem to be seeking a software recommendation so researching/asking at the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange seems to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

[JTS](https://github.com/locationtech/jts) is your best free open source option. The method you are looking for in JTS is [here](http://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry.html#intersects(org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry))

As far as commercial options, you have [ESRI's Java JNI version](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/java/api/arcobjects/index.html) of their ArcObjects library which has a very robust Geometry Library. The interface on ESRI's library is called [ITopologicalOperator](http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/geometry/ITopologicalOperator.html)

If all you are trying to do is Geometric operations, JTS is your best option - it is an excellent library which has many ports to different languages. If, on the other hand, you are looking for an entire GIS system that does complex symbology, supports GIS workflows and multiuser editing, printing, etc etc, then I would start looking at the ESRI libraries.

Comment: Missed Kendrics link:   New URL : http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html

Comment: A free option from Esri: https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java

Comment: agreed. In my defense, it did not exist in 2010 :)

Comment: Beware that JTS is still a complete disaster for 3D (it messes up the z coordinate). I tried creating a facade to deal with it but I gave up after the unit testing for corner cases showed that it would be a lot of work.

Answer (score 6):

The package you should look at it `java.awt.geom`, which is part of the JDK.

In particular check out the [`java.awt.geom.Area`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html) class, which allows you to perform intersection operations between two `Shape`s.

**EDIT**

Finding the intersection points is non-trivial as far as I know, as you need to apply a different algorithm depending on the shapes you're analysing.  For example, the algorithm for the intersection between two circles is given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html), whereas the algorithm for calculating the intrsection between two Bezier curves is completely different ([here](http://www.truetex.com/bezint.htm)).

**EDIT 2**

One suggestion: You could look into the `PathIterator` class, which returns a description of a shape's path as a sequence of segments.  In particular check out `FlatteningPathIterator`, which will collapse any curves into multiple straight lines.  Once your path has been reduced to straight lines, calculating the intersection points will be simple ... although obviously this is an approximation in cases where your shape contains curves.

Comment: but the results are only true/false. I need the exacts intersection points

Comment: comment to EDIT: so far I know, once we know the equation of the path it is pretty straightforward to get intersection points. Maybe I will end up creating the library myself if there is no sophisticated solution out there.

Answer (score 6):

For non-GIS purposes I may suggest **javaGeom** library. It uses the Euclidean abstraction of geometry which most of the people know from school. There's no recent activity on this project, but I find it well structured and easy to use. They say it supports boolean operations, but never tested how well they work. There is a pretty feature-rich testing application named Euclid, which is developed from the same author.
You can try to use it, but only if you are sure it's gonna work for you.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/geom-java/

Comment: It looks like they've had 3 releases in late 2011, after a long period of inactivity.  Also, the library looks much more compact than JTS--nice not to bloat things too much!

Comment: check [this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/114761/36681) too, I found many alternatives

Answer (score 4):

I found that JTS has changed hands, or changed home sites, or something.  A newer version can be found here: http://maven.geotoolkit.org/com/vividsolutions/jts/1.10/

Edit:  This might be its new home page: http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html

Edit:  Moved again! https://locationtech.github.io/jts/

Answer (score 2):

JTS - Java Topology Suite - is the best.

http://www.vividsolutions.com/jts/jtshome.htm

It is free, fast, robust, and can handle degenerate intersections.

Comment: Another name change with the later versions. Much of the documentation out there still references the old stuff. Same [JTS library](https://github.com/locationtech/jts) here.