# how can i find the minimum distance between two or more polygons?

Tags: java, javascript, google-api

I want to find the minimum distance between two polygons. but I had some problems to find it. I am new with google maps, so can you help me? I have those coordinates to use;

```
    polygonArray = [[
       new google.maps.LatLng(40.56389453066509,33.739013671875),
       new google.maps.LatLng(40.39676430557206,32.135009765625),
       new google.maps.LatLng(39.87601941962116,36.046142578125)
    ]];
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a geometry library that computes distances between two points, the center of a polygon, etc. Take a look at this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2115976/34880).

Comment: This nails it nicely. Good one.

Answer (score 4):

in case you decide to write your own code:

for 2 non-overlapping polygons, the simplest code (from the programatical point of view) would iterate through one polygons' points and find the distances between EVERY point in one polygon and EVERY LINE in the second  polygon and then do the same for the second polygon (every point to every line).

in case you are not sure whether polygons overlap, you must also check if every line in one polygon does not cross ANY other line in the second polygon (only need to do this for 1 polygon).

Answer (score 0):

The below piece of code solved the problem partially, but still need enhancing by detecting the points on the edges that is more near to the other polygon, as this part works only on vertices

```
        static double solve(List<List<Integer>> p, List<List<Integer>> q) {
        double minLength = 100000000;
        for (List<Integer> qq : q) {
            for (List<Integer> pp : p) {
                double current = distanceBTWPoints(pp, qq);
                if (current < minLength) {
                    minLength = current;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(minLength);
        return minLength;
    }

    static double distanceBTWPoints(List<Integer> p, List<Integer> q) {
        double xDiff = q.get(0) - p.get(0);
        double yDiff = q.get(1) - p.get(1);
//        if(xDiff==0 || yDiff==0)
//            return 0;
        System.out.println(+p.get(0) + "  " + q.get(0) + "  " + p.get(1) + "  " + q.get(1) + " x:" + xDiff + "  y: " + yDiff + " p: " + ((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff)) + " VAl= " + Math.sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff)));
//        System.out.println("p.get(0): "+p.get(0) +"  q.get(0) :"+q.get(0) +"  p.get(1):  "+p.get(1) +"  q.get(1): "+q.get(1) +" xDiff: " + xDiff + "  yDiff: " + yDiff + " plus: "+((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff))+ " VAl= " + Math.sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff)));
        System.out.println("--" + Math.hypot(xDiff, yDiff));
        System.out.println("--" + Math.sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff)));
        return Math.hypot(xDiff, yDiff);
    }
```