# Minimum distance between two polygons

Tags: java, convex-polygon

I have worked on implementing the algorithm required for detecting minimum distance between two convex polygons P and Q, but I reached only detecting the distance between vertices, how can I detect the minimum distance when on edges of the polygons.

What is needed exactly, what are native java can do with edges to find the minimum distance?
Is there direct native Java methods calculate the points on the edges and how to use within my code piece below?

```
        static double solve(List<List<Integer>> p, List<List<Integer>> q) {
//        confirmPositiveArea(p);
//        confirmPositiveArea(q);
        double minLength = 100000000;
        for (List<Integer> qq : q) {
            for (List<Integer> pp : p) {
                double current = distanceBTWPoints(pp, qq);
                if (current < minLength) {
                    minLength = current;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(minLength);
        return minLength;
    }

    static double distanceBTWPoints(List<Integer> p, List<Integer> q) {
        double xDiff = q.get(0) - p.get(0);
        double yDiff = q.get(1) - p.get(1);
//        if(xDiff==0 || yDiff==0)
//            return 0;
        System.out.println(+p.get(0) + "  " + q.get(0) + "  " + p.get(1) + "  " + q.get(1) + " x:" + xDiff + "  y: " + yDiff + " p: " + ((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff)) + " VAl= " + Math.sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff)));
//        System.out.println("p.get(0): "+p.get(0) +"  q.get(0) :"+q.get(0) +"  p.get(1):  "+p.get(1) +"  q.get(1): "+q.get(1) +" xDiff: " + xDiff + "  yDiff: " + yDiff + " plus: "+((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff))+ " VAl= " + Math.sqrt((xDiff * xDiff) + (yDiff * yDiff)));

        return Math.hypot(xDiff, yDiff);
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<List<Integer>> p = new ArrayList<>();
    List<List<Integer>> q = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(1);
    p.add(list1);
    list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(10);
    list1.add(1);
    p.add(list1);
    list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(10);
    list1.add(5);
    p.add(list1);
    list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(2);
    list1.add(5);
    p.add(list1);
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(15);
    list2.add(10);
    q.add(list2);
    list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(20);
    list2.add(10);
    q.add(list2);
    list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(20);
    list2.add(15);
    q.add(list2);
    list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(15);
    list2.add(15);
    q.add(list2);
    System.out.println(solve(p, q));
}
```

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, they're a relatively new user, and this is their first question, likely they did not post it that way intentionally.. Why not [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52451283/edit) their question and show them how to properly post their code?

Comment: I am asking on different implementation in Java, if there is a library generates the required distance directly without mathematics based algorithms

Comment: If you understand the algorithms explained in the other question, try implementing them. Have you tried that?

Comment: Not the point of the question, but you can write your lists much more easily with `Arrays.asList`: `Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(2, 1), Arrays.asList(10, 1) /* etc */)`.

Comment: e.g.: https://github.com/simplegeo/jts/blob/master/src/com/vividsolutions/jts/operation/distance/DistanceOp.java

Comment: Links are not opening in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700983/what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-to-calculate-the-minimum-distance-between-two-sets

Comment: Both are not native JDK based, they external libraries, I need algorithm to loop on edge points and compare the vertices sample in the main post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115976/geometry-library-for-java
and 
https://github.com/simplegeo/jts/blob/master/src/com/vividsolutions/jts/operation/distance/DistanceOp.java

Comment: Links worked now, I think there is need for VPN, but I don't understand how to implement the algorithm

Comment: Dears, Why the site redirects me to another question?. I noted that the algorithm considered as a solution is not understandable and not also fulfilling the requirement I'm asking for.

Comment: I need to add a solution for this question in Java but number of characters not allowing me